# How to implement Polynomial long division in matlab

Tags: matlab, mupad

I am looking for a way to implement [Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) in Matlab. My expected result such as

[image]

where `x^3-2x^2-4` is the dividend, and `x-3` is the divisor

Could we have any way or matlab tool to show all processes such as above example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
u=[1 -2 0 -4]; %coefficients of dividend
v=[1 -3]; %coefficients of divisor

[r,p,k]=residue(u,v);
```

You would get r=5, p=3, k=[1 1 3] as results.

Comment: Thanks, However, i want to show all processes of division such as first step is x^3-3x^2., second step....